# Safety for American visiting London, UK

Tags: uk, safety, london, scams

I'm traveling from Seattle, USA to London, UK in March 2020. My cousin (half British) is getting married to his British girlfriend in Farnham. I'm a 40 year old American, single, white man.

I did a lot of international travel as a child with my family but have only been to Canada as an adult (Vancouver), which wasn't too difficult as it's very similar to America. I'll be staying near Hyde Park.

**Any tips on how to stay safe in London?**

I'm just a little concerned about getting robbed or mugged. I currently live in Redmond, which is a very safe suburb of Seattle.

Comment: On Stackexchange you best ask a single question per posting. That makes it easier to give a solid answer.

Comment: Related questions: [What are the most dangerous areas of London north of the River Thames?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81223/what-are-the-most-dangerous-areas-of-london-north-of-the-river-thames), [How to protect yourself better against knife-crime in London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/113173/how-to-protect-yourself-better-against-knife-crime-in-london). Quick answer: You've got nothing to worry about with regards to personal safety.

Comment: Thanks Peter M. I removed the place I'll be staying at. I just said I'll be staying near Hyde Park.

Comment: According to https://www.travelsafe-abroad.com/cities/ Seattle is judged to be more dangerous than London

Comment: Other than what you would do in any city? Probably nothing.

Comment: Quick tip - any entertainers performing the 3-cup trick on London Bridge or any of the other central London bridges are scam artists. don't get drawn into it.  If you want a bit of fun, wait until they get a crowd and then shout "police!" and watch them leg it.

Comment: Nice. I'll do that! Thanks Moo.

Yes, in some big cities in the US we have Three-card Monte (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-card_Monte) which is a very similar scam.

Comment: Under the heading of not making things easy for pickpockets, I avoid the crowds that gather around 3-cup and similar. Those are a good place to find distracted people bunched tightly together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm a 70-year-old woman. I visit London about once a year, because it is one of my favorite cities, I used to live there, and my relatives all live in England.

I do the things I expect most people do in tourist areas, such as not flashing a lot of cash, and not making life easy for pickpockets.

Otherwise, I pay far more attention to avoiding traffic accidents. The combination of unfamiliar side of the road, complicated one-ways, dense traffic, and pedestrians who are both familiar with the intersection and impatient, makes for a dangerous mix.

Comment: Thank you Patricia. From all the answers London seems like a safe enough place to visit. It even seems like Seattle (the big city I live close to) may be slightly more unsafe.

Yes, I think the cars traveling on the left side of the road will probably be my biggest adjustment.

I'm super excited for my trip!